# trying to use an array to input 10 numbers then writing them out after each outher

Tags: c#

Like the titel says im trying to input numbers in an array then print them after all ten numbers are written.
Right now i can write ten numbers but there is a 0 in the line after the number i write in and after everything is written out only a 0 is printed

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] tenNumbers = new int[10];
        int userInput = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tenNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
            userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(tenNumbers[0]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You read into `userInput` but then print `tenNumbers[0]` - there is not connection between these two variables. You probably want to actually assign values to the array instead

Comment: Create two loops, in the first loop, prompt the user to enter a number, read the input, use `int.TryParse` to parse it to an int (if the parse fails, tell the user) and then assign it to `tenNumbers[i]`. In the second loop (which could be a `foreach`) loop over `tenNumbers` outputting the contents of the array

Answer (score 1):

You should write user input into your array

try this one

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int[] tenNumbers = new int[10];
    int userInput = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tenNumbers.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        tenNumbers[i] = userInput ;
        Console.WriteLine(tenNumbers[i]);
    }
  //upd for ptinting
     for (int i = 0; i < tenNumbers.Length; i++)
     {        
      Console.WriteLine(tenNumbers[i] + "\t");
     }
     foreach(var n in tenNumbers)
     {
     Console.WriteLine(n);
     }
}
```

Comment: That makes it so that the number i write in comes up after i've written it, how do i make it so that all the numbers i've written comes out after the loop is finished?

Comment: just add one more loop like this:

for (int i = 0; i < tenNumbers.Length; i++)
   {
        
        Console.WriteLine(tenNumbers[i] + "\t");
    }

or you can use foreach loop to iterate your collection

foreach(var n in tenNumbers)
{
  Console.WriteLine(n);
}

Comment: I've updated answer, you can see solution above

Comment: For printing, you missed one: Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", tennumbers)); - string classes can do it out of the box, thus simpifying code.